# Problema ao usar listen firebase com mobx

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

**Olá, boa tarde!**

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no firebase utilizando o listen para ser notificado toda vez que um documento for alterado. Porém, o listen é sempre notificado mas, o widget em si não, mesmo utilizando o observer.

O widget só é alterado com a atualização do firebase caso eu troque de tab e retorne para a mesma, o que não deveria estar acontecendo. Pois, estou observando a lista com o mobx..

**InitState:**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addPedidosListener();
  }
```

**Build:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _pedidosBloc = BlocProvider.of<PedidosBloc>(context);

    return Observer(
      builder: (_){
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: pedidosModel.listPedidos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){

            if(index == 0){
              return Column(
                children: [
                  _parteFiltro(_pedidosBloc),
                  CardPedido(pedidosModel.listPedidos[index])
                ],
              );
            }

            return CardPedido(pedidosModel.listPedidos[index]);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**Listen:**

```
Future<void> addPedidosListener() async{
Pedido pedido;
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pedidos").doc("Kwdqc77luBnyPdS2AqD4").collection("pedidos").snapshots().listen((snapshot) {

  snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) {
    String pedidoId = change.doc.id;


    pedido = Pedido.fromDocumentSnapshot(change.doc);

    switch(change.type){
      case DocumentChangeType.added:
      //========== quando um pedido for adicionado ==========
        pedidosModel.addPedido(pedido);
        break;
      case DocumentChangeType.modified:
      //========== modificado ==========
        print("modificou");
        print(pedido.status);
        Pedido pedidoGlobal = Pedido.recuperarPedidoGlobal();
        if(pedidoGlobal != null && pedido.idPedido == pedidoGlobal.idPedido){
          Pedido.setarPedidoGlobal(pedido);
        }

        pedidosModel.removeWhere(pedidoId);
        pedidosModel.addPedido(pedido);
        break;
      case DocumentChangeType.removed:
      //========== removido ==========
        pedidosModel.removeWhere(pedidoId);
        break;
    }
  });

  //_sort();

});
```

}

**Mobx:**

```
part 'PedidosModel.g.dart';

class PedidosModel = _PedidosModel with _$PedidosModel;

abstract class _PedidosModel with Store{

  @observable
  List<Pedido> listPedidos = [];

  @action
  void addPedido(Pedido value){
    listPedidos.add(value);
  }

  @action
  void removeWhere(pedidoId){
    listPedidos.removeWhere((pedido) => pedido.idPedido == pedidoId);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na questão do Mobx, para se trabalhar com listas reativas é preciso uma pequena mudança

Ao invés de usar uma simples lista, como essa:

```
List<Pedido> listPedidos = [];
```

É preciso que você utilize uma `ObservableList`, dessa forma:

```
ObservableList<Pedido> listPedidos = <Pedido>[].asObservable();
```

Deixo abaixo o código completo da sua *Store*:

```
part 'PedidosModel.g.dart';

class PedidosModel = _PedidosModel with _$PedidosModel;

abstract class _PedidosModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<Pedido> listPedidos = <Pedido>[].asObservable();

  @action
  void addPedido(Pedido value){
    listPedidos.add(value);
  }

  @action
  void removeWhere(pedidoId){
    listPedidos.removeWhere((pedido) => pedido.idPedido == pedidoId);
  }

}
```

### Explicação

A *ObservableList* fica observando seus itens, então quando um novo é adicionado ou excluído ela notifica o *Observer* de que algo ocorreu.

> Atenção: Esse tipo de lista não vai escutar mudanças feitas nas
> propriedades de cada item dela, como por exemplo, se você alterar o
> *status* de algum dos itens da lista, nada será notificado.

Se quiser utilizar listas "normais", como já estava fazendo `List<Pedido>`, é preciso que uma nova lista seja setada na propriedade  *listPedidos* a cada alteração em seus itens, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
  @action
  void addPedido(Pedido value){
    listPedidos.add(value);
    listPedidos = List.from(listPedidos);
  }
```